# Clear contaminated vector of Strings in R

Tags: r, string, list, vector

I have a list of strings in R contaminated with some undesirable characters "X." and ".", like this:

```
"age", ".name", "X.marks", "X.study.time", "class", "X.number"
```

And I want to parse the string data to:

```
"age", "name", "marks", "study time", "class", "number"
```

Meaning, I want to remove "X." if it exists and substitute every "." for " " (space). How can I do this in R?

Comment: I'm assuming a caveat on the pattern you're describing is that periods should only be replaced with spaces when they're in between words—is that right? Otherwise `".name"` would become `" name"` with a space at the beginning

Comment: Are they always `X.` or some other letter also exists?

Answer (score 3):

We may use `sub`

```
gsub(".", " ", sub("^X?\\.", "", v1), fixed = TRUE)
[1] "age"        "name"       "marks"      "study time" "class"      "number"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("age", ".name", "X.marks", "X.study.time", "class", "X.number")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the desired substitution with the `str_replace_all` function from the `stringr` package. Using the `v1` object posted by akrun:

```
library(stringr)
# Replace all "X." by nothing and all "." not preceded by "X" by spaces
str_replace_all(v1, c("X\\." = "", "(?<!X)\\." = " "))

# "age"        " name"      "marks"      "study time" "class"      "number"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `stringr` solution combining two functions:

```
library(stringr)
str_trim(str_replace_all(v1, "\\.|X", " "))
```

```
[1] "age"        "name"       "marks"      "study time" "class"      "number"
```